# Approximating an integral by evaluating the cumulated sum

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am using a cumulated sum to approximate an integral.

My initial thought was that the integral in the interval from a to b by evaluating the cumulated sum at b and a, and subtract.

When I do this, however, I always seem to underestimate the integral leading me to think that the integral is better evaluated as $C(b)-C(a-1)$ instead.

Can this really be true? If so, why?

**E.g. in IPython**

```
data = (0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0)
csum = cumsum(data)
A = csum[4]-csum[2]
```

`A` gives 3 and not 4 (which is the sum of 1, 2 and 1).

Comment: You need to provide some details. Like what integral, what method, etc.

Comment: What do you mean what integral and what method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to describe what method you are using.  It appears you are suspecting a fencepost error, which is possible.  Another source of underestimate is that we tend to draw functions that are increasing.  If one element of your sum is $(x_{i+1}-x_i)f(x_i)$ you may have a systematic error.  Better is to take as that element $(x_{i+1}-x_i)(f(x_i+\frac 12(x_{i+1}-x_i))$ or $(x_{i+1}-x_i)\frac 12(f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1}))$ Both are exact for linear functions.

Comment: Your addition does seem to show a fencepost error.  If you want to add up data[2] through data[4], then you do need csum[4]-csum[1].  This has nothing to do with integration, it is just keeping the data[2] term in the sum.

Comment: It must have something to do with integration? In a sense, the cumsum is the antiderivative function of data, and so the area under data from a to b, must be a subtraction of cum[b]-csum[a]?